# Wrong data returned getting sold products per store

Tags: magento-1.9, product-collection, store-view

I'm trying to get all sold products for a specific store view using the following code.

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addOrderedQty($fromDate, $toDate, true)
        ->setStore(4)
        ->addStoreFilter(4)
        ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
echo '<pre>';
echo ($_productCollection->count());
```

This only returns 2 products, but If I look in the backend at orders for that given date range there are a total of 4 products.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE :**

I found that if I create an order from the backend using a configurable product then it's not visible using my code, is it possible to get that data?

Comment: Try to use reindex of products.

Comment: @VadymKalin : yeah still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I've done in following way

```
$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$toDate))
            ->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
            ->addFieldToFilter('store_id',$storeId);
foreach ($orders as $_order):
  $orderitems = $_order->getAllVisibleItems();
  foreach ($orderitems as $orderitem):
    $_product = $orderitem->getProduct();
  endforeach;
endforeach;
```

And it's returning proper data.